# why i am getting An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine in android studio

Tags: android

Here is my error

```
Target device: samsung-sgh_i727
Installing APK: G:\Milan\StudioProject\BluetoothDemo\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.domore.bluetoothdemo
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

I tried lot more i restarted my adb,disconnect my device with pc and connect again but every time i got similar error.

Please, give me valid reason.
What will i need to do to solve out this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate means what?

Comment: your answer is already there

Answer (score 2):

**In case of Android Studio**

> Close the ide (Android Studio)
>
> Then Open Task Manager and check if the studio running -> Check java too -> If running close that too.
>
> Then start your Android studio again. Your issue resolved!!

**If that doesn't work**

> Go to **FILE** > **Invalidate Caches / Restart....**

Comment: There is no instances are open  in task manager.

Comment: check for Java(TM) Platform SE binary in the processes tab..if running close that...and restart Android Studio